# MariaDB error on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql, database, mariadb

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a real machine, not a virtual one.
And right away installed mariaDB from:

```
apt install acl apache2 composer fping git graphviz imagemagick libapache2-mod-php7.0 mariadb-client mariadb-server mtr-tiny nmap php7.0-cli php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql php7.0-snmp php7.0-xml php7.0-zip python-memcache python-mysqldb rrdtool snmp snmpd whois
```

Once I rebooted the system, opened the terminal, and tried to restart the mysql, I got this error in the attachment.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart mysql

Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with
error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe"
for details.
```

Here are the details saved in a file as they are 30 pages !

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1knJZB3SFeiNJna5X4fV3MfpY3ci1T-QijS5d8zDjaUQ/edit

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you installed MariaDB?

Comment: Did mariadb work in the first place? If yes there should be no difference before or after any reboot.

Comment: @abu_bua I added the source into the main question.

Comment: @tardis It has never worked before as it's a new installation. Right after install, I checked the status and it was Active (in green). For no particular  reason, I rebooted the pc and once I restarted the mariadb, i got the mentioned error.